# ASP.NET MVC 4 Editor Template for basic types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I've created a template for Number input and if I do

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeValue, "Number")
```

it works fine and the template is used.

However that doesn't work:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeValue)
```

Why do I need to specify the name of the Editor Template for basic types ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Editor templates work by convention. The name of the template must match the name of the type. So for example if `SomeValue` is an `int` type you could write a custom editor template at `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Int32.cshtml` which will be used. In this case all integer types will use this custom template when you write `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeValue)`.

If you don't want to override all templates for integer types you could write a specific named template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Number.cshtml` that you could use only for some properties by specifying this template name as second argument to the `EditorFor` helper: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeValue, "Number")` or by decorating your view model property with the `[UIHint]` attribute:

```
[UIHint("Number")]
public int SomeValue { get; set; }
```

and then simply using `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeValue)` will render the `Number.cshtml` custom template.

I would also recommend you reading Brad Wilson's [`blog post`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) about the default templates in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: that's great, I'm going to use the UIHint attribute. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The second file name should be `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Number.cshtml`. The dot before `Number.cshtml` must be replaced with a slash.

Comment: Can you get the default .cshtml files for the built in editors if you want to make a small change and use those with the sight modifications?  The link provided the .ascx option.

Comment: @Xaxum, yes you can do that with Razor templates as well. All you have to do is translate the code shown in the linked article to Razor which is a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

In your Editor Template, you must have the same type
Example :

model.SomeValue is type of loremIpsumObject

In your EditorTemplate you are :

```
  @model YourNamespaceWhereIsYourClass.loremIpsumObject
  ...And your code in your editorTemplate....
```

you can find an example [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx) for datetime

It helps you ?