# MVC 5 model properties null when ajax form submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Im creating a model and passing it to a partial view. When I submit the model ModelStat.IsValid is true yet of its properties are null regardless of what value I enter on the form.

**Controller and model**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model.SomeFieldName= "Test";
        model.OtherFieldName = "AnotherTest";
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        if(ModeState.IsValid)
        {
            //Do Stuff to model
        }
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string SomeFieldName;
        [Required]
        public string OtherFieldName;
    }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model Portal.Controllers.TestController.TestModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Content" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="Content">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SomeFieldName,"FieldName")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeFieldName)
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherFieldName ,"OtherFieldName")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OtherFieldName )
       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />

    </div>
}
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236412/1384945) I replaced

```
public PartialViewResult Index(TestModel model){}
```

with

```
public PartialViewResult Index(FormCollection model)
{
    var val = model["SomeFieldName"];
    var otherVal = model["OtherFieldName"];
}
```

I was able to access the values through the FormCollection with but I cant get them into my model. Any ideas on whats keeping my model from being populated correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need getters and setter on your properties

```
public string SomeFieldName { get; set; }
public string OtherFieldName { get; set; }
```

As your method signature is `public PartialViewResult Index(TestModel model)` the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `TestModel` then attempts to set the value of its properties based on the posted values, but cant do so because your properties do not have setters.

Comment: I've been pounding my head against my screens trying to figure this one out. A big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your model class as follows

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeFieldName {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string OtherFieldName {get; set;}
}
```

Now why it is working with FormCollection  and not with test model.

When you ask for formcollection you will get all the fields of form submitted to post method that is why you can access all the fields from the form.

When you mention particular class TestModel something know as **model binding** comes in picture what us does is, it try to map submitted values with properties from model. Mark the word properties because property will have get and set method. If it finds set property then model binder will successfully map and replace values in your model.