# Format Date to only Month and Year - "MMM-yyyy"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am working on MVC 4.0./C#/Razor view. In model I have a date

```
[Display(Name = "For Period")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")] 
public System.DateTime ForPeriod { get; set; }
```

and in View I am getting date using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ForPeriod)
```

and in result I am getting date in "12-May-2015" format. I want to skip the day from this date and in result I want "May-2015".

My question is what should I used in View to get this "MMM-yyyy" format?

Comment: Just drop the `dd-` and use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}")] `

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Should be in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @irfi - Welcome to StackOverflow!  Being that this is your first question I encourage you to read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  Good Luck and Welcome!

Comment: Well I am deleting my answer because technically as @VulgarBinary said it will not work in view for `DisplayFor` but the same will work for `TextBoxFor`. By oversight I missed that part!! :) and 1st format as VulgarBinary has already answered I don't think that's needed here again.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format date in View file by following way

```
<span>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.EffectiveDate).ToString("MMM-yyyy")</span>
```

For can also format date from model

```
[Display(Name = "For Period")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}")] 
public System.DateTime ForPeriod { get; set; }
```

Comment: Putting the `@Convert.ToDateTime(...)` inside of a view is bad practice.  The ViewModel should have the field in the data type needed.  If it is a date and you are using an annotation you would simply do `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EffectiveDate)` and not what you posted.  The `[Display(...)]` copy and paste was incredibly impressive, I can't fathom how long it took you to arrive at that as part of your answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
[Display(Name = "For Period")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}")] 
public System.DateTime ForPeriod { get; set; }
```

More information on formatting dates in C# can be found [on MSDN here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There is an additional option of using a custom editor template which you can read this article on stack overflow for more details - [ASP.NET MVC 4 Editor Template for basic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655930/asp-net-mvc-4-editor-template-for-basic-types)

Answer (score 0):

Code to Convert Current Date to Month-Year format in ASP.NET

CASE - 1

```
Dim Current_Date as String = DateAndTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

msgbox(Current_Date) //THIS WILL DISPLAY CURRENT DATE IN SHORT STRING FORMAT
```

For Example = `"05/07/2020"`

CASE - 2

```
Dim Current_Date as String = DateAndTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-yyyy")

msgbox(Current_Date) //THIS WILL DISPLAY CURRENT MONTH & YEAR
```

For Example = `"July-2020"`