# Repeated UI functionality in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few screens which have duplicated complex UI functionality. i.e. Drop down A triggers a JSON call to my Controller, which populates the values in drop down B and C, based on the value selected in drop down A.

So, on the screens, I have drop down A, and then under that, B and C.

This is duplicated UI code on 3 screens (Growing to 5 soon). But they make use of the same Controller call to do the population.

Is there a way I can create a partial view, which I can place in a form (Form is submitted via a normal Form post), and the values of the selections can then be passed back with the values of all the other form items that are submitted? The partial view would have the markup, as well as the Javascript I use to call the controller?

I'm not sure if I can then include the values within the partial view, in the Form post, and have them available to the controller.

I have started investigating EditorTemplates, but all I have is the Model for the template:

```
public class AccountCombinationTemplateModel
{
    public int SourceEntityId { get; set; }
    public int DestinationEntityId { get; set; }
    public int EntityEventTypeId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Accounts { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ThirdParties { get; set; }

}
```

and an empty AccountCombinationTemplate.cshtml file. Not sure if I need a controller etc.

My parent model (The main model I use for the view) now references the new model created above:

```
public AccountCombinationTemplateModel AccountModel { get; set; }
```

So all the properties that were in the parent model, have been moved into the AccountCombinationTemplateModel.

On my View, I now have:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(Model.Details.AccountModel)
```

That is on the view, where I want my Drop downs to appear.

I created a new empty view called AccountCombinationTemplate.cshtml in my View\Shared\EditorTemplates folder.

That view looks like this:

```
@model BasicFinanceUI.Models.AccountCombinationTemplateModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-3 divAccounts">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EntityEventTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EntityEventTypeId, Model.EntityEventTypes, new { @class = "EntityEventTypeId form-control", @onchange = "changeDisplay(this)" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-5 divAccounts">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SourceEntityId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SourceEntityId, Model.Sources, new { @class = "SourceEntityId form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-5 divAccounts">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DestinationEntityId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DestinationEntityId, Model.Destinations, new { @class = "DestinationEntityId form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I my existing controller, I have added the new EditorModel above as a property of the main model for the view, and populated it and it's properties.

But when I run the screen, where I have the @Html.Edit..., nothing is rendered. No errors either. It;s as if it can't find the View?

Comment: How is the first dropdown created? Do you bind it to your model? I have a hunch you could actually create an editor template.

Comment: Yes you can use a partial view. but don't include scripts in a partial - include them in the main view. Exactly how you do this will depend on your models and are the dropdownlists related to properties in your model

Comment: @AndreiV - At the moment, I have the lists passed in as 'Public List<SelectListItem> Accounts {get; set;}'. I populate these from the intial controller call. But on change of the 'triggering' drop down, I call the controller with JSON query, and 'repopulate' the dropdown.

Comment: I've added my investigation into EditorTemplates. But not sure how this works yet.

Comment: Personally, I find that your requirement sounds just like a "component", i.e. widget. That's why I suggested a custom template. If you look at it like that, you just add the mark-up and script inside the template; it would be a component that you could use in several places but you don't need to duplicate the logic.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiV - that's what I am hoping to do, but ... not quite understanding how. I have a model, added the model to my parent model, but not sure how to create the View.

Comment: It depends on how you generate your view. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655930/asp-net-mvc-4-editor-template-for-basic-types) for a start.

Comment: Do you mean you have various models that contain a property `public AccountCombinationTemplateModel MyProperty { get; set; }`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - No, not yet, but I think that is the plan. At the moment, I have all those properties (in the question above) in all my models. (Repeated). I'd like to change it, as well as the Views, to be more of a components.

Comment: Then an `EditorTemplate` is the best approach. Re you edit - you note that the template is named `AccountCombinationTemplate.cshtml ` but it needs to be named `AccountCombinationTemplateModel.cshtml ` (must match exactly the name of your model) and then it just needs to be `@Html.EditorFor(Model.Details.AccountModel)`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - I've renamed everything, but now I get edit boxes for the properties. It's not using the view I created (Which should have drop down lists). I also get an error when using the EditorFor syntax you mentioned. But this is 'allowed': @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Details.AccountModel)

Comment: @Craig - saying you get an error, then not telling us what that error is, is kind of pointless.  Where did you put your template?  It must be in a folder called EditorTemplates or DisplayTemplates (if using DisplayFor), either in the current View folder, or in the Shared view folder.

Comment: Sorry @ErikFunkenbusch - The error was in debug mode, and the syntax was invalid (Red line under the text). 'The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage'.

Comment: @Craig, sorry, that was a typo - yes it should be `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Details.AccountModel)`

Comment: Just not finding the view. Should the cshtml file be a 'View' or a 'Partial View'? Or doesn't it make a difference (Both cshtml files).

Comment: Wait.. It finds the model now, but I'm getting null exceptions. So, not populating my 'DropDownListFor values correctly.

Comment: @Craig - if you're getting Null exceptions, it's because you're not passing valid data to the view.  ie, your model is null, or the sub-model Details is null.  You need to create instances of these before you call the View.

Comment: Thanks @ErikFunkenbusch - All fixed now. Next step is to somehow have a shared constructor somewhere so that I can populate the List data in a single method. The view doesn't have a Controller - should there be one, or should I just have a method in another controller that I can call, and populate the model's reference data?